# Why do I keep getting redirected with jQuery and cant stop redirecting?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm having difficulty trying to display the 'result' message without getting redirected to the insert.php file. The 'result' message should display without reloading. Please help. Much appreciated.

**html code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP AJAX TUTORIAL</title> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Enter Product</h1>
        <form method = 'post'  action = 'insert.php'>
            <input type = "text" id = "n" name = "productname" placeholder = "Product name"></br>
            <input type = "text" id = "b" name = "brandname" placeholder = "Brand name"></br>
            <input type = "number" id = "q" name = "quantity" placeholder = "Quantity"></br>
            <button>Save Product</button>
        </form>


        <p id = "result"></p>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php

    // The browser (HTML) sends inforamtion to the server(php) using $_POST 
    $name = $_POST['productname']; //'productname' is from html input
    $brand = $_POST['brandname']; //'brandname' is from html input
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity']; //'quantity' is from html input

    $con = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '', 'tutorial');

    if ($con -> connect_error) {
        echo 'database connect error';
    }

    //Prepare statement to insert into database
    $stmt = $con -> prepare ("INSERT into products(name, brand, quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    // Bind the variables to the values
    $stmt -> bind_param ("ssi", $name, $brand, $quantity);
    //Execute
    if($stmt -> execute()){
        echo "success";
    }
    else {
        echo "failure";
    }

    ?>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post(
            'insert.php',
            {
                productname:$('#n').val(),
                brandname:$('#b').val(),
                quantity:$('#q').val()
            }

            function(result){
                if (result == "success"){
                    $('#result').html("Values inserted successfully");
                }
                else{
                    $('#result').html("Error!");
                }
            }
        );

    });


});
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: may be add return some_value; in your submit function

Comment: you really should be giving your form an id or name and reference that in your script.js

Comment: @Cigar Fox if you are going to follow techLove comment you should include `return false` as last line in the function `$('form').submit(function(e){`

Comment: @RaymondNijland why return false? `e.preventDefault()` negates the need for returning false

Comment: @CigarFox, you have a syntax error after your variables - you forgot a comma (before the function).  If you press f12 and look at your console, it will tell you about any js errors that occur

Comment: @Pete I inserted the comma but it still not working.

Comment: @ATechGuy Yes, I need to id my form. Thank you!